# Polynomial factorization over finite fields with non-prime order

Tags: polynomials, factorization, finite-fields

One can easily factor a polynomial over finite fields of prime order, using `Factor` command:

```
Factor[1 + x^2, Modulus -> 2]
===>  (1 + x)^2
```

Now, is it possible to do this over finite fields of non-prime order? As an example, $ x^2 + x + 1$ is reducible over GF(4), and can be decomposed as $(x-a)(x-a^2)$, where $a\not\in \{0,1\} $ is a field member.

Problem is, members of non-prime order finite fields are not denoted by ordinary numbers; rather, they use either polynomial or vector notation.

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/FiniteFields/tutorial/FiniteFields.html  It says `Factor` will not work with the Finite Fields package.

Comment: @MichaelE2: So, Mathematica offers *no way* to factor over finite fields with non-prime order?

Comment: No built-in functions that I know of.  Others might.  You could implement an algorithm or you could perhaps use MathLink to call PARI from within *Mathematica*: http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/mathlink.html  See also [this related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16159/how-to-do-the-polynomial-stuff-over-finite-fields-extensions-fast) and the answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks for introducing me to MathLink. I used [GUAVA](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/guava.html) to do math over finite fields, but I'm gonna take a look at PARI/GP, as it can be called from Mathematica using MathLink.

Comment: You may be able to call a GAP script.  See [GAP FAQ](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#8.1), [Run, etc.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CallingExternalPrograms.html), [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28605/capturing-external-command-output#comment89193_28605), the discussion of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6876/calling-external-commands-without-showing-command-prompt-on-windows/6879#6879).

Comment: One way to go about this would be to implement the Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm over finite extensions to prime fields.