# Abstract algebra: define constants in a finite field

Tags: algebra

How can I to define a constant in $Z_{2}$?

For example, I want to create a constant `b` that inherits the properties of an element from $Z_{2}$. For example

```
b + b = 0
b^n = b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question focuses on the wrong aspect of finite fields. It's not the numbers 0 and 1 that change because you are working with $Z_2$, it's the arithmetic operators. You could define your own operators `plusZ2` and `TimesZ2`.

An alternative is to load the [finite fields package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/FiniteFields/tutorial/FiniteFields.html) with `` Needs[FiniteFields`] ``, which overloads the relevant arithmetic operators for you.

Comment: Great! You are right! Thanks. But... I have some large polynomials whose coefficients are in  $Z_{2}$... for example: $p(X)=(a+b^2+c^4+5b^6....)X+(.....)X^2+....$ So, how can I simplify $(a+b^2+c^4+5b^6....)$ in a authomatic way? (suppose $(a+b^2+c^4+5b^6...)$ is in arithmetic of $Z_2$)

Comment: @user14545. Advise you to follow the link I provided.

Comment: @user14545. Previous comment is not a brush-off. I simply don't have the experience to help you with the new question you pose in your comment. Try to use the finite fields package. If have trouble solving your problem with it, come back with a new question, which is specific to applying the package to your polynomials.

Comment: Thanks again. I saw the package that you recommend, but I had some problems. So... I ask again: I load: Needs["FiniteFields`"];
 fld = GF[2] And, I want to do: a^3+a^2
I write:
fld[{a^3}] + fld[{a^2}]
but mathematica give me:
Subscript[{Mod[a^2 + a^3, 2]}, 2]
And I'd like mathematica give me: 0

Comment: @user14545. Please do not ask new questions in a comment. This is not a discussion forum. Bring what you ask above to the attention of the community by writing it up as a new question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'm new here. I'll do my questions in a new.
Thanks again.

Comment: (1) I would advocate avoiding the FiniteFields` package. I'll offer instead [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16159/how-to-do-the-polynomial-stuff-over-finite-fields-extensions-fast) and [also this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15140/finitefields-package-is-very-slow-any-fast-substitute-for-mathematica). Both indicate some ways to get viable finite field functionality.

Comment: (2) Possibly some of what you seek could be done with existing polynomial functionality using the `Modulus` option.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. OP might not see your useful comments because you didn't tag him with @.

Comment: I thought both OP and immediate responder (you, that is, @m_goldberg, since my comment was on your response) were always notified when a comment is made. If that's not the case, let me know and I'll repeat them tomorrow with a tag as you suggest.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. It's me who is likely wrong. I can't say I understand how comment notifications work.