# Package FiniteFields

Tags: finite-fields

In a *Mathematica* session, I evaluate:

```
Needs["FiniteFields`"];
fld = GF[2];
```

Now, for example, I'd like to compute $a^3+a^5$ for $a \in{Z_2}$. The result I'd like to have is $0$, because in $Z_2$, $a^n=a$ and $a+a=0$.

I tried:

```
fld[{a^3}] + fld[{a^2}]
```

But *Mathematica* gives me:

```
Subscript[{Mod[a^2 + a^3, 2]}, 2]
```

How can I simplify $a^3+a^2$ in $Z_2$ to get zero?

Comment: It would seem I gave you some bad advice. Daniel Lichtblau made some useful comments [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48378/3066). You should read them.

Comment: My advice conflicts in some ways with that of @m_goldberg. I do not claim that advice was bad-- for some purposes the `FiniteFields` package might in fact be what's needed. I only advocate avoiding it when there are alternatives, as it is unmaintained and moreover sometimes will do, in technical parlance, "weird things".